# html mobile menu sizeing

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

i want a mobile dropdown menu but my problem is that the items in my menu dont add a space between. 
i allready tried to change widht but than it wasnt in the center anymore. 
how it should look like.
[image: how it should look like]
how its actually look
[image: how its actually look]

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Monaco", "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace;
    text-align: left
}
body {
    padding: 0 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0
}
header {
    max-width: 70%;
}
h1.undertitle {
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    font-size: 75%;
    word-spacing: -0.25em;
}
h1.undertitle::before{
  content: none;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial
}
.container  a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.625em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.625em 1em;
    background-color: inherit;
}
/*.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: black
}*/

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 10em;
    /*box-shadow: 0em 0.5em 1em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    z-index: 1
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.625em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd
}*/
.show {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Alan Pijak</h1>
  <h1 class="undertitle">
    intressiert sich für <span class="orange w700">Java</span> und <span class="blue w700">C++</span>
  </h1>

  <div class="container">
   

    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Startseite</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">Startseite</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bootstrap for this , like for a mobile view , use

`<div class="col-xs-4"> Menu Item -1 </div>`

`<div class="col-xs-4"> Menu Item -2 </div>`

`<div class="col-xs-4"> Menu Item -3 </div>`
Now its all done , because bootstrap divides a row in 12 columns and you can also individually adjust it !!

Answer (score 0):

I made a few HTML adjustments to give the navigation a more rigid structure and I also added a few small CSS changes such as removing the absolute positioning and a few floats that aren't needed with a list structure.

The menu should be centered now and under the top level link.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
window.myFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Monaco", "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace;
    text-align: left
}
body {
    padding: 0 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0
}
header {
    max-width: 70%;
}
h1.undertitle {
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    font-size: 75%;
    word-spacing: -0.25em;
}
h1.undertitle::before{
  content: none;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial
}

.container  a {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.625em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown {
    overflow: hidden
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.625em 1em;
    background-color: inherit;
}
/*.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: white;
    color: black
}*/

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 10em;
    /*box-shadow: 0em 0.5em 1em 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
    z-index: 1
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.625em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd
}*/
.show {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Alan Pijak</h1>
  <h1 class="undertitle">
    intressiert sich für <span class="orange w700">Java</span> und <span class="blue w700">C++</span>
  </h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
       <ul>
          <li><a class="dropbtn" onclick="window.myFunction()">Startseite</a></li>
          <ul class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` on `myDropdown` and `dropdown`

Snippet below

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Monaco", "Menlo", "Consolas", monospace;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 0 1.25em 1.25em 1.25em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0
}

header {
  max-width: 70%;
}

h1.undertitle {
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  font-size: 75%;
  word-spacing: -0.25em;
}

h1.undertitle::before {
  content: none;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial
}

.container a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.625em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background-color: #333;
  min-width: 10em;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.625em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<h1> Alan Pijak</h1>
<h1 class="undertitle">
  intressiert sich für <span class="orange w700">Java</span> und <span class="blue w700">C++</span>
</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Startseite</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">Startseite</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```